# What other active internet communities exist that overlap with this site?

Tags: discussion

It's worth getting a sense of what other *fora* already cover sustainable living. One use would be to mine them for questions that aren't well-addressed in that format, but would be well-addressed in the StackExchange format.

Comment: I don't think 'mining questions' from other sites is a good idea. The best questions are usually practical questions about things you've encountered yourself.
I do think it is good to build a list of SE sites and one for non-SE sites that have a large overlap with sustainability. The first list can be used to refer users to the appropriate SE site when a question is off-topic. The second list can be used to promote questions that have been asked here and hopefully draw new people to this site.

Comment: Mining isn't really particularly helpful, but inspiration is a totally different story. Additionally, it's good to get to know your 'neighbors' - you definitely want to shoot for as good (if they're awesome) quality, or better if not. Additionally, where are they promoting? If you're going to get inspiration - that's definitely something to investigate.

Answer (score 5):

**StackExchange sites**

- [Gardening SE](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/) topics include: [composting](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compost), [organic gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organic), [permaculture](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permaculture), [vermicomposting](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vermicomposting)
- [Home Improvement SE](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) sustainable construction materials, [insulation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insulation), making your home more sustainable / [energy efficiency](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy-efficiency)
- [Personal Finance & Money SE](https://money.stackexchange.com/) save money by reducing energy consumption or waste
- [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) relevant tags include [renewable energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/renewable-energy), [building physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/building-physics), [climate science](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate-science), [photovoltaics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photovoltaics)
- [Seasoned Advice SE](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) ingredients from sustainable farming, [organic food](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organic)
- [Skeptics SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/) e.g. [climate change](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate-change), [climatology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climatology), [energy-efficiency](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy-efficiency)
- [Electronics SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com) e.g. solar panel installation, [solar cell](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solar-cell), [energy harvesting](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy-harvesting)
- [Chemistry SE](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com) e.g. [green chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/green-chemistry), [environmental chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/environmental-chemistry)

**StackExchange beta sites**

- [Earth Science SE](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/), e.g. [climate change](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate-change), [global warming](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/global-warming), [environmental protection](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/environmental-protection), [pollution](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pollution)
- [Engineering SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/), e.g. [energy](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy), [energy-efficiency](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy-efficiency), [renewable-energy](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/renewable-energy)
- [Politics SE](http://politics.stackexchange.com) e.g. [sustainable development](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sustainable-development), [ecology](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecology), [global-warming](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/global-warming)
- [Veganism & Vegetarianism SE](http://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com) e.g. [environment](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/environment), [global-warming](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/global-warming)

Answer (score 4):

http://permies.com/ - permaculture, defined very broadly. For example, solar power is on topic there.

Answer (score 2):

## LinkedIn groups

**which may have interesting questions we could take here, and then point those groups to the answers here**

Note that these are **discussion forums** and we are **not**. So most of the questions asked there, would **not** be appropriate questions for here. But some would.

- [Advanced Energy Economy: the business voice of advanced energy](http://www.linkedin.com/groups?gid=3577)
- [CleanTech](http://www.linkedin.com/groups?gid=52038&trk=myg_ugrp_ovr)
- [DESERTEC](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/DESERTEC-2113510?trk=myg_ugrp_ovr)
- [ecoConnect - UK cleantech (green & low carbon industry) business](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/ecoConnect-UK-cleantech-green-low-2069494?trk=myg_ugrp_ovr)
- [Energy + Environment Science, Technology & Innovation Policy](http://www.linkedin.com/groups?gid=4002275&trk=myg_ugrp_ovr)
- [Green](http://www.linkedin.com/groups?gid=67451&trk=myg_ugrp_ovr)
- [Renewable Energy Network](http://www.linkedin.com/groups?gid=40102)
- [The UK District Energy and District Heating Group](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/UK-District-Energy-District-Heating-3669697?trk=myg_ugrp_ovr)

Answer (score 1):

The main competitor sites of Stack Exchange are Quora and Yahoo Answers!. Both have sections about sustainability-related topics:

**Quora:** (requires registration to read)

- [Sustainability](http://www.quora.com/Sustainability)
- [Sustainable Technology](http://www.quora.com/Sustainable-Technology)
- [Energy Efficiency](http://www.quora.com/Energy-Efficiency)
- [Alternative Energy](http://www.quora.com/Alternative-Energy)
- [Solar Energy](http://www.quora.com/Solar-Energy)
- [Recycling](http://www.quora.com/Recycling)
- [Waste Materials](http://www.quora.com/Waste-Materials)
- [Composting](http://www.quora.com/Composting)
- [Climate Change](http://www.quora.com/Climate-Change)

**Yahoo Answers:**

- [Green Living](http://answers.yahoo.com/dir/index;_ylt=ArCScrae7Qo7i2FN2bPS2o_95nNG;_ylv=3?sid=2115500307)
- [Global Warming](http://answers.yahoo.com/dir/index;_ylt=ArCScrae7Qo7i2FN2bPS2o_95nNG;_ylv=3?sid=2115500306)
- [Alternative Fuel Vehicles](http://answers.yahoo.com/dir/index;_ylt=AvEyiU6_91yT1iD4Jt6LnIz_5nNG;_ylv=3?sid=2115500148)