# Can we hold a contest to design and select a new site logo? What would the contest look like?

Tags: discussion, design

Why a new Logo and a Contest? To help move this Stack Exchange site (Sustainable Living beta) up from page 12 of 15 to at least page 6/15 of the ~170 sites by 'traffic',and move it off beta (status for almost 6 years) now that the Responsive-design is now available Dec 7/2018  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319089/responsive-design-now-available-on-all-sites-new-theme-customization-coming-soo

I realize I should post this Question in the meta site associated with this site, but since I have no Reputation here yet, I must start this way.

Comment: Thanks for moving the post here to meta where it belongs. I will work hard to get some Rep here, I am at 49 in the Meta SE, so it will grow here, I am sure.

Answer (score 1):

I would love to see a logo for our site so we have a more distinct and recognizable appearance. In [this recent Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319274/responsive-design-themes-what-can-sites-customize-and-how-can-they-get-changes) it says that

> If your site's users feel like there are ways we can help re-establish some degree of now-missing identity to your site, create a meta post and start talking about it on your site. Consider focusing your meta post on a specific part of the design - the background, the header content, the logo, etc. - as this will help limit the discussion so that it's not "everything is awful".

However at the moment this is for graduated sites only (see also [this question on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321059/164138)). As Catija mentions in [her comment below this post](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300/can-we-hold-a-contest-to-design-and-select-a-new-site-logo-what-would-the-conte#comment355_302) there are plans to also allow this for beta sites, but apparently the discussion on this is still on-going.

Once beta sites are allowed to change their logo, we can hold a contest and select a winner. However I feel this has to be a decision of the entire Sustainable Living community. So if we go forward with this, we should create a post here on Meta where everyone can post their idea for a logo and we can simply use the voting system to see which logo is most popular.

There already was [a brief attempt at this 4 years ago](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/183/99)
but with little response. That is also the risk here. I think there is only a small group of people that visit Sustainable Living SE on a daily or weekly basis, and not many visit Sustainability Meta. If we have only a few people participating in this logo selection process chances are that the StackExchange community managers won't grant our wish for a logo.

To get more attention and have better and more proposed logos we could post a question in [Graphic Design SE Meta](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com) to ask if people there are willing to help create logos.

For now we just have to wait....

Comment: As a note, for the time being, the content of that MSE post you quote is specific to sites with custom themes. That's implied in the "re-establish some degree of now-missing identity"... beta sites had the standard theme, so they had no individual design based identity... That said, part of the plan of the new site designs was to make it possible for the beta sites to get ... something... at this point we're still figuring out what the rollout of that is going to be like and what "graduation" will look like moving forward. So, when we do get to that, any thoughts you have will be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

[image: And the Winner is...]
For this Contest, I am imaging things like Top 10 Reputation members here as Judges perhaps, Reward for Best Design: how about 'recognition' with perhaps some Swag from Stack Exchange Co.?

Promote the contest here, other SE sites, and the world, somehow. Run it for 'X' weeks, with Contest open to '?' people, and so on...

The result, a new Logo for the new Design when it arrives, that sets this site apart from others, is meaningful for those who are serious about living in a Sustainable way, on this planet. A planet that is certainly being stressed by Global Warming now, by loss of Diversity, continued Pollution of Air, Water and Land - those and more messages are needed to be broadcast from this site, a message for the many new visitors who arrive (looking for more than just the New Logo... :-)