# Closing reason for off-topic questions

Tags: discussion

Yesterday I wanted to flag [this question](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/which-paperboard-wood-is-not-healthy-for-cooking-barbecue) as being off-topic. However if I want to flag this as off topic I only have two options:

- It should be move to gardening
- It should be moved to meta

The question does not fit any of those, but is still off-topic.

Is there a reason why there is no generic off-topic option? I know [this](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148/what-will-our-list-of-close-reasons-look-like) has been discussed previously, but in the end it does not seem to have been implemented.

Comment: I'm not sure, it may have something to do with the 'Question should be moved to gardening' option that was added. I temporarily disabled that option. Could you check if the default 'not related sustainabe living' option is visible for you now?

Comment: Yes, I can see it now! Shouldn't the 'gardening' option be under the section "belongs to another SE site"?

Comment: Ideally yes, but it seems we cannot add specific site suggestions while we are still in beta.

Answer (score 1):

The close reason system is slightly complicated.

The default off-topic close reason ('This question does not appear to be about sustainable living within the scope defined in the help center.') is only displayed when there are no 2 off-topic reasons. It seems that because we added a custom off-topic reason ('Questions on gardening that don't need to be answered with sustainability in mind are off-topic here.') there are always 2 off-topic reasons, so the default option isn't displayed anymore.

I think it's better to have the default close reason instead of the 'gardening' reason, so I've deactivated the 'gardening' reason until we come up with a better solution.

BTW, people with enough reputation (I'm not sure where the limit is) can see a third close option called 'Other', but apparently this reason doesn't count towards to 2 off-topic reasons for displaying the default option.

Comment: can't you make a second custom off-topic reason for the generic one and in this way keep the gardening?

Comment: Yes, that is an option. But we can [only create 3 custom options](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6996) so I'm a bit reluctant to use up 2 reasons just for this. Also off-topic reasons [should be drawn up carefully](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185097/164138) and need to be approved by 2 mods so it's not something we can change easily.

Comment: I believe that you need the "cast close and reopen votes" priv to see the "Other" option, which on sustainability.SE is at 500 rep. IIRC, if you have this rep and select Other, the button changes from "Flag" to "Vote", i.e. it's just another route to Vote To Close.